# Gap on the right side when transitioning width

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've a vertical full screen menu, with three columns. On hover, the actual columns width grow, the others shrink. The only problem, that there is a little gap on the right side when the cursor is moved fast between columns.

The [code](http://jsfiddle.net/by89sp8a/):

```
.service-navigation {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.service-navigation:hover .service-navigation-element {
    width: 30%;
}

.service-navigation:hover .service-navigation-element:hover {
    width: 40%;
}

.service-navigation-element {
    width: 33.333333%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: .6s ease;
    float: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

How can I remove that gap, and why is it there?

Comment: Quick fix: add `background-color: blue;` to `.service-navigation`.

Comment: The backgrounds are images, so this is not a solution. :\

Comment: It's just the way CSS transitions work. They're not really suited for this. My advice would be go with progressive enhancement: remove the CSS transition effect and add the animation using Javascript.

Comment: @Michael That's not how I would use the term [*progressive enhancement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). On topic: the only possible solution that I see is to have an overlap. I.e. from left to right or the other way around. This would require you to start working with position absolutes and z-index and I don't think it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I remove that gap,...

*One* solution could be to use `flex`. It will make things much easier and smooth. Just change the `flex-basis` on hover.

**Example 1**:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
body, html { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }
.service-navigation { height: 100%; width: 100%; display: flex; }
.service-navigation-element { flex: 1 1 33%;  transition: .6s ease; }
.service-navigation-element:hover { flex-basis: 50%; }
.service-navigation-element:nth-child(1) { background-color: red; }
.service-navigation-element:nth-child(2) { background-color: green; }
.service-navigation-element:nth-child(3) { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="service-navigation">
    <div class="service-navigation-element">1</div>
    <div class="service-navigation-element">2</div>
    <div class="service-navigation-element">3</div>
</div>
```

*Another* solution could be to use `display: table` on the container and `display: table-cell` on the children.

**Example 2**:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
body, html { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }
.service-navigation { height: 100%; width: 100%; display: table; }
.service-navigation-element { display: table-cell; width: 10%; transition: .6s ease; }
.service-navigation-element:hover { width: 20%; }
.service-navigation-element:nth-child(1) {  background-color: red; }
.service-navigation-element:nth-child(2) { background-color: green; }
.service-navigation-element:nth-child(3) { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="service-navigation">
    <div class="service-navigation-element">1</div>
    <div class="service-navigation-element">2</div>
    <div class="service-navigation-element">3</div>
</div>
```

However, there is a problem with this second approach. You have to provide an initial width to the children (*`width:auto` will not fire transtions*). Also, it is not possible to precisely control the width of the children once hovered. The `table-cell` would re-calculate the widths on its own. I would recommend the first approach of using `flex`.

> and why is it there?

I think that it is because of these two rules:

```
.service-navigation:hover .service-navigation-element {
    width: 30%;
}
.service-navigation:hover .service-navigation-element:hover {
    width: 40%;
}
```

When you hover on the container, all the children start reducing to `30%` width from `33.3333%`. When that happens there will be extra space on the right (`30 * 3 != 100`). Meanwhile, the child on which hover is fired starts increasing its width to `40%`. When you do it slowly, there is enough time for both the transitions to complete smoothly. However, when you hover quickly then one transition is not yet complete when another starts and it abruptly ends, causing flicker.

Comment: Thanks. The first works perfectly, but IE does not support transition for flex-basis. Insted of this, with setting the width, works good in all browsers.

Answer (score -1):

The gap results from the animate-style.
The default [transition-timing-function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) is ease-in-out, wich can be described in a cubic [bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). possible solutions may be to set `transition-timing-function: linear` or adding a [transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay).

Also the animation-duration is calculated everytime you enter an element. So leaving an element while its at full width and then quickly reentering it will cause the animation from 90% width to 100% width to be the full .6s long

Comment: I didn't down vote, but linking to some external documentations is *good* **if** you actually provide a solution. However, you don't. Therefore, your post should've been a comment.

Comment: Transition-delay sounds super fiddly and I very much doubt it will work at all. Transition timing was my first thought but that doesn't work either - presumably for the reason in your second paragraph.